# Kohana session exception

Tags: исключения, сессия, php, kohana

Со вчерашнего дня в логах коханы начали появляться такие записи:

```
2014-11-03 11:07:30 --- EMERGENCY: Session_Exception [ 1 ]: Error reading session data. ~ SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Session.php [ 324 ] in /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php:125
2014-11-03 11:07:30 --- DEBUG: 0 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php(125): Kohana_Session->read(NULL)
1 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php(54): Kohana_Session->__construct(Array, NULL)
2 /www/application/classes/Controller/Main.php(20): Kohana_Session::instance()
3 [internal function]: Controller_Main->__construct(Object(Request), Object(Response))
4 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Request/Client/Internal.php(94): ReflectionClass->newInstance(Object(Request), Object(Response))
5 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Request/Client.php(114): Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(Object(Request), Object(Response))
6 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Request.php(986): Kohana_Request_Client->execute(Object(Request))
7 /www/index.php(118): Kohana_Request->execute()
8 {main} in /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php:125
2014-11-03 12:07:29 --- EMERGENCY: Session_Exception [ 1 ]: Error reading session data. ~ SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Session.php [ 324 ] in /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php:125
2014-11-03 12:07:29 --- DEBUG: 0 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php(125): Kohana_Session->read(NULL)
1 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php(54): Kohana_Session->__construct(Array, NULL)
2 /www/application/classes/Controller/Main.php(20): Kohana_Session::instance()
3 [internal function]: Controller_Main->__construct(Object(Request), Object(Response))
4 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Request/Client/Internal.php(94): ReflectionClass->newInstance(Object(Request), Object(Response))
5 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Request/Client.php(114): Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(Object(Request), Object(Response))
6 /www/system/classes/Kohana/Request.php(986): Kohana_Request_Client->execute(Object(Request))
7 /www/index.php(118): Kohana_Request->execute()
8 {main} in /www/system/classes/Kohana/Session.php:125
```

(свежий лог)

При этом вчера были такие же ошибки.
Увидел закономерность, что эта ошибка возникает раз в час.
Посмотрев в логах сервера (сегодняшние), увидел, что оба раза эксепшен был выброшен для одного и того же IP, при этом была запрошена только главная страница сайта. /

Тип сессии native (по дефолту).

В чем может быть проблема?

P.S. Эксепшн вылетает далеко не всегда, и непонятно, почему он вылетает, из-за каких причин, поэтому нет возможности отследить все это дело.

## UPD

Сейчас в логе ошибок php нашел строки:

```
    [03-Nov-2014 11:07:30 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'' in Unknown:0
Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: Kohana_Core::error_handler(2, 'Unknown: The se...', 'Unknown', 0, Array)
1 {main}
  thrown in Unknown on line 0
[03-Nov-2014 12:07:29 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'' in Unknown:0
Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: Kohana_Core::error_handler(2, 'Unknown: The se...', 'Unknown', 0, Array)
1 {main}
  thrown in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Файл `bootstrap.php` в UTF-8 без BOM сохранен? Или, может, где-то `session_start()` прописано?

---

А еще быть может, что php не может записать сессию в директорию на сервере.

Comment: @Bastian  bootstrap.php без BOM в UTF-8. session_start() только в system/classes/kohana/session/native.php.  Если бы он не мог писать в директорию, то он бы всегда сыпал эту ошибку, а так, он её выкидывает очень редко. (сегодня 2 раза на более чем 170 хитов)

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло SYSPATH/application/configsession.php

поправить 'encrypted' => FALSE, вместо TRUE. Просто отключил его.

```
'database' => array(
        'name' => 'session',
        'encrypted' => FALSE,
        'lifetime' => 3600, //43200
        'group' => 'default',
        'table' => 'sessions',
        'columns' => array(
            'session_id'  => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents'    => 'contents'
        ),
        'gc' => 500,
    ),
```

копайте в сторону, наверное он не установлен. 
Смотрите у себя в phpinfo()
apt-get install php5-mcrypt